# Django 1.6 IOError

Tags: django, ioerror

I have upgraded my django version from 1.5.2(if i don't remember bad) to 1.6 and now when i execute my project on localhost i get this error:

```
IOError at /
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2-0.8-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/top_level.txt'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Django Version: 1.6.1
Exception Type: IOError
Exception Value:    
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2-0.8-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/top_level.txt'
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py in _get, line 1320
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.5
```

Comment: I would recommend you using a virtualenv..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like a **Permission Error**. Try to change the permissions with the `chmod` command (http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/chmod-command-examples/).

For example

```
sudo chmod -R 755 problematic_folder
```